# Add custom attribute in eloquent model

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Here is a raw SQL query:

```
SELECT name, area, point(area) AS center FROM places;
```

I want to get an Eloquent model based on this query. Here is the Model:

```
class Place extends Model
{
    protected $visible = ['name', 'area'];
}
```

So, I want to get the `center` property if I run this code:

```
return response()->json( Place::all() );
```

`center` is missing. I don't know how to add the `center` property in my `Place` object. **I don't want to build a raw query in my controller, is there any solution with mutator or something like this?** (The only thing I want to call is `Place::all()`, I really want to use Eloquent Model in controllers, not an SQL query).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a combination of Mutators and the `$appends` property. Here's an example:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Place extends Model {

    protected $appends = ['center'];

    public function getCenterAttribute()
    {
        return $this->point($this->getRawAttribute("area"));
    }

    protected function point($area)
    {
        // logic for SQL POINT(), etc
    }
}
```

The `$appends` property will mean that the mutated attribute is included in JSON/array output when `$model->toJson()` or `$model->toArray()` is called (which `Response::json()` does)

The reason for doing point logic in code is because with eloquent models, you'd hit the N+1 query problem when fetching a list of places and their centers, and that's not a great idea for your database.

Your query wouldn't be used when fetching data for the model from the database, either, since the default query for models is

```
select * from `table` where id = :id
```

Which is then figured out internally to set up data on the model.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I'm not sure to understand everything yet; so i can't use the "power" of postgresql for this? (it can transform polygon to a center point). I have to write a custom php code for this?

Comment: You can technically use a custom query, but it still has performance penalties. I can't remember if raw expressions are allowed in `$columns`; i'll check that now

Comment: But when i save the object which contains appended field then it will going to update the filed. How to prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#global-scopes. It should help you build the query that will always get center along with the rest of data.

Comment: OP has tagged laravel-5 in which they're implemented slightly differently if I recall correctly. Might want to update with the correct docs.

Comment: In addition, OP may not need to use a global scope if they're happy with doing `Place::center()->get();`. Normal scopes are much quicker to implement and slightly more verbose for those looking at code later.